# piecewise regression with two breakpoints to be fitted in R: a horizontal line, a straight line and then again a horizontal line

Tags: r, regression, breakpoints, piecewise

I want to do a piecewise regression with two breakpoint in R: first a horizontal line with slope 0, then a linear line and then again a horizontal line with slope 0. The two breakpoints should be fitted also.

My data looks like this (in total I have 60 similar datasets):

```
x <- c(1.306, 1.566, 1.736, 1.854, 2.082, 2.328, 2.650, 2.886, 3.162, 3.392) 
y <- c(176.4, 188.0, 193.8, 179.4, 134.4, 119.0, 66.2, 58.2, 58.2, 41.2)
```

Anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: If it might be of some use, I found that a Gaussian peak equation with offset "a * exp(-0.5 * pow((x-b) / c, 2.0)) + Offset", with parameters a = 1.4554605225541448E+02, b = 1.5839534147665826E+00, c = -5.6899030064297440E-01, and Offset = 4.6871995528236809E+01 gave an OK fit yielding  R-squared = 0.9865 and RMSE = 6.742

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nls` to fit a line with a minimum and maximum on `x` like this.  `a` and `b` are the x values of the intersection points and `.lin1` is the intercept of the middle portion and `.lin2` is the slope of the middle portion.

```
fm <- nls(y ~ cbind(1, pmax(pmin(x, b), a)), alg = "plinear", start = list(a = 2, b = 3))
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ cbind(1, pmax(pmin(x, b), a))
   data: parent.frame()
       a        b    .lin1    .lin2 
   1.774    2.764  425.463 -134.940 
 residual sum-of-squares: 530.7

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.489e-09
```

The horizontal portions are at the y values corresponding to the x values of the intersection points:

```
predict(fm, list(x = coef(fm)[1:2]))
## [1] 186.06667  52.53333
```

or can be computed as the y values corresponding to the smallest and largest x values:

```
predict(fm, list(x = range(x)))
## [1] 186.06667  52.53333
```

We can plot the points and the fit like this:

```
plot(y ~ x)
xx <- seq(min(x), max(x), length = 100)
p <- predict(fm, list(x = xx))
lines(p ~ xx, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This really is a big help, thank you! The only problem is that I have 60 of these datasets and the range of x differs. So for some the starting values are working and for some not.

Comment: For example another dataset is:
x <- c(2.434, 2.89, 3.08, 3.15, 3.404, 4.494, 3.674, 3.758, 3.9, 4.13) 
y <- c(129.2,104,96.6,105.4,85.6,71.4,82.4,65.4,64.4,65.6)
where Error:  singular matrix 'a' in solve  appears

For some other datasets: Error:  step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562 appears instead.

Comment: I tried these as starting values:
a0 = min(x, na.rm = FALSE) + 0.3;
b0 = max(x, na.rm = FALSE) - 0.3

Comment: Assuming you have removed NA's, another possibility is `start = list(a = mean(head(x, k)), b = mean(tail(x, k)))` where `k` is chosen appropriately.  Your starting values correspond to k=1.  If some of your data does not really follow this model then you likely won't get convergence for those sets so it may not be realistic to expect a completely automatic result.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer to require less human interaction, Still,
basically the same answer as before.

You can coarsely group the points into the upper and lower 
points automatically. Some of the transition points might 
get grouped with the upper or lower points, so we use 
`boxplot.stats` to eliminate anything that looks like an 
outlier in these groups.  We can then take the mean of the 
high and low points to estimate the heights for the horizontal 
lines.   We also use the non-outlier upper and lower points to 
determine the x values for the transitions.

```
HighLine = (2*max(y) + min(y))/3
HighPoints = which(y >= boxplot.stats(y[y>HighLine])$stats[1])
HighY = mean(y[HighPoints])

LowLine = (max(y) + 2*min(y))/3
LowPoints = which(y <= boxplot.stats(y[y<LowLine])$stats[5])
LowY = mean(y[LowPoints])

x1 = max(x[HighPoints])
x2 = min(x[LowPoints])

plot(x,y)
lines(c(min(x), x1,x2, max(x)), c(HighY, HighY, LowY, LowY))
```

[image: Piecewise Linear fit]